# SQLite ORDER BY query returns two different orderings?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two databases that have a lot of similar values. Namely, they have a unique key, let's call it UID.

In table 1 I have these two keys

```
blahblahblahYebAAA=
blahblahblahYeBAAA=
```

And in table 2 I have the same two keys.

Now when I do a search query for `uniquekey = blahblahblahyebAAA=` ordered by unique key,

for both databases I get these two keys (not sure why it's not case sensitive) and their ordering is entirely different. For database one I get `bAAA=, BAAA=` and for database two I get the reverse ordering. This ordering is interfering with a program I'm writing to compare these values, any ideas how to get the ordering to match up?

Comment: what's the collation on your table/field? if it's case-sensitive, then `b` and `B` are two totally different characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COLLATE BINARY` to make the ordering case-sensitive:

```
ORDER BY {key} COLLATE BINARY
```

and the filtering:

```
WHERE key = 'blahblahblahYebAAA' COLLATE BINARY
```

Comment: I was working with a database that had been made case-insensitive, so that explains the issue, thanks!